# what is the max limit of mysql int 11?

Tags: mysql

I [read](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm) that you can specify the max limit of `int` to be 11. Why is this if in 4294967295 there are only 10 digits?

Comment: A signed integer may require a `-` as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the "display width", not the maximum storage size.  That means it can take ten characters to write the digits and perhaps one character for a minus sign in the negative case, so 11 characters are the most necessary to write the integer.

For more info, see:

http://waynewhitty.ie/blog-post.php?id=19

and

https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/what_does_the_11_mean